# Unable to locate package ros-groovy-desktop-full

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I installed ros-groovy-desktop-full in my ubuntu 12.10. Then I updated to ubuntu 13.04 and everything worked fine.

I've uninstalled ros-groovy-desktop-full(with apt-get rm), also removed directories ~/ros_workspace and ~/.ros, and update ~/.bashrc.

Now I'm trying to reinstall again ROS in ubuntu 13.04, using this line in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list:
deb ...ros.org/ros/ubuntu raring main
but I get this message:
Unable to locate package ros-groovy-desktop-full.

Only works when I put
deb ...ros.org/ros/ubuntu quantal main
But quantal is for ubuntu 12.10 and it's not my current version.

Is it ok for the rest of the installation and configuration?
Should it work with the line "raring" ?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68221/unable-to-locate-package-ros-groovy-desktop-full/) by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Groovy` binary is not prepared for Ubuntu `Raring` 13.04.

Installing `Groovy` on Raring is still possible. See the [previous thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/64032/how-to-install-groovy-on-ubuntu-1304/) where a few options presented.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2